# Application is not defined error in Trix/action text setup in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trix

I have scoured stack overflow and the internet for what is going wrong here but have not come up with anything useful yet.  I am trying to setup my blog application with trix/action text.  I believe I have done everything correctly, but now I am getting the following error `application is not defined` .  I believe this has something to do with these 3 lines in my `application.html.erb` file.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

The way my simple blog application is setup is I have 3 models, articles (belong to devise user), comments (belong to articles), and devise (for authentication).  I want to use the trix editor for making new comments as well as editing and creating new articles.  Here is one of my form partials that should be working properly and when I get the `application` error only a small gray rectangle will be shown in lieu of the editor.

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<%= form_with model: article do |form| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title, class:"form-control"%>
    <% article.errors.full_messages_for(:title).each do |message| %>
      <div><%= message %></div>
   
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <br>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= form.rich_text_area :body %>
  <br>
  <br>
  </div>
    <% article.errors.full_messages_for(:body).each do |message| %>
      <div><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

   

  <div>
    <%= form.label :status %><br>
    <%= form.select :status, ['public', 'private', 'archived'], selected: 'public' %>
  </div>
   <br>
  <div>
    <%=  form.submit "Submit", class:"btn btn-outline-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

[What is show in lieu of the editor][1]

Additionally here is my `application.js` file

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require trix 
import Rails from "@rails/ujs";
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks";
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage";
import "channels";
import "trix";
import "@rails/actiontext";
import "bootstrap";
 

Rails.start();
Turbolinks.start();
ActiveStorage.start();

require("trix");
require("@rails/actiontext");
```

and the relevant part of my `application.css` file.

```
/*
.
.
.
.
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require trix
 *= require_tree 
 *= require_self
 */
```

My rails application was previously having trouble finding the `trix.js` and `trix.css` files and was reporting a 404 because of that.  I don't know if that is fixed but it is probably very related.  Has anyone experienced these issues before?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf2if.jpg

Comment: where's your `application.js` ? is it in `app/javascript/pack` folder ? if it's you have to use `javascript_pack_tag` instead.

Comment: Yes my ```application.js``` file is located in ```app/javascript/pack```.  When I change the tag ```javascript_tag``` to ```<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>``` however, I get the following error 

```undefined method `javascript_pack_tag' for # <ActionView::Base:0x000000000088b8>
Did you mean?  javascript_path javascript_tag ```. Where can I go from here?

Comment: `javascript_pack_tag` is a function of the [rails/webpacker gem](https://github.com/rails/webpacker), it's not belongs to Rails(core). So are you using `webpacker` ?

Comment: Oh I see yes I am using gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0' in my gemfile.  Do I need to perhaps ```bundle remove webpacker``` and then add it back to my gemfile?